# Ansible command failed because during vm is reeboting

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to install using ansible a 'application.exe' file in a windows vm.
During the installation phase , the vm is restarting and ansible script is failling because the connection is dropping. The install is succesfull , but FAILED in the script.
Do you have any idea how can I bypass this issue?

```
- name: Install app
  win_command: "application.exe"
  args:
    chdir: "C:\\App\\Patch4"
  ignore_errors: true
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  register: task_result




TASK [install_exe : Install app] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.13.174.244]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "\"app.exe\" ", "delta": "0:02:57.048216", "end": "2022-08-18 14:20:55.430716", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1641, "start": "2022-08-18 14:17:58.382500", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`wait_for_connection` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_connection_module.html), so you can wait until the remote host is available.

If necessary you have to or should execute the [`setup` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) afterwards, so that the facts are reloaded.

```yaml
- name: Your reboot task
  debug:
    msg: "Dummy. Only printing reboot."

- name: Wait for system to become reachable
  ansible.builtin.wait_for_connection:

- name: Gather facts for first time
  ansible.builtin.setup:
```